# How to implement a gamification system in ASP.NET Web Application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm building a Web Application using ASP.NET MVC and I'd like to implement a Gamification system to make the user experience more exciting.

I'd like to start with a simple score for each user and as they progress and get more points they get badges and unlock new features for themselves, something similar to how Stackoverflow does it.

What appears challenging to me is how to check in the entire application, whether a user has reached a score that can recieve a badge. I don't want to duplicate my code and perform this check in every place that I'm incrementing a user's score.

I'd like to know how can I start implementing such a system. I know it's a broad question but I'm just looking for some starting ground and some good practice to begin.

Comment: Create events for what's happening in your system and let the gamification system listen on those events. Then map awards to the event types. For instance the user should get the "Frequent visitor" badge if they have generated the login event 5 times in a day. Each badge should have it's own tables to keep track of the event stream for it.

Comment: @RickS, as explained in the rest of that sentence, I'm not looking for a complete solution. Only some starting point to begin i.e an example or a reference to an article about it.

Comment: @jgauffin, Creating events does seem the way to go. `Each badge should have it's own tables to keep track of the event stream for it`. I didn't fully understand that part. Would you explain how a table for "Frequent visitor" badge would look like?

Comment: For frequent visitor it would just contain `userId, date, visits` while othe badges would require one or two tables to store the information to track progress towards the badge. You would also have to have a table to track the awards. Something like `userId, badgeName, awardedAt`

Comment: @jgauffin, Thanks for the explanation. Just to make sure I'm on the same page, let's consider "Frequent badge" again. When a user has successfully logined, I broadcast an event called "Login" for example. Then when my gamification system catches this event, it increments the `visits` of a user in the corresponding table for that `date`. Then checks if the number of visits is actually more than 5. If it's the case, it awards the user with that badge. This is the concept, right?

Comment: that's how I would do it.